# Google-api-php-client error:Codegniter Class 'Basecontroller' not found?

Tags: php, codeigniter

api-php-client-2.0.2 in my Codegniter project, but have this error message "Class 'Basecontroller' not found?".

This is my include files:

```
require_once "google-api-php-client-2.0.2/src/Google/Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client-2.0.2/vendor/autoload.php";
```

Structure in my project application/controlers/google-api-php-client-2.0.2/

```
class Event extends Basecontroller {

        function createEvent() {
            // This is my Authconfig info when work and get info "client_secret.json".

            $client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setAuthConfig('/home/remarke/public_html/test.ibroker.bg/application/controllers/google-api-php-client-2.0.2/client_secret.json');
            $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
            $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
        }

    }
```

Where is problem? I have Fatal error "Class 'Basecontroller' not found" Why?

Comment: Where is this `BaseController` defined ? did you import the it with the `use` statement ?

Comment: Basecontroller is used from my class Event for work.

Comment: When remove extends Basecontroller function "createEvent work", but no work view.

Comment: that is not the question, where is this class defined and if it is defined in an other namespace, did you import it ?

Comment: To work my project each my controler  "extends Basecontroller".